# trouble getting data from react input form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am just making a simple app to learn react with redux.
I just want to get data input in the react input form on the server-side.
The problem is that the params on the server-side is like this.

{"item"=>{"name"=>"undefined","price"=>"undefined"...}...}

Here is part of my code:

```
import React from "react";

class ItemForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }


  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      const ItemData = new FormData();
      ItemData.append("item[name]", this.props.item.name);
      ItemData.append("item[price]", this.props.item.price);
    };

  update(field) {
    return (e) => {
      this.setState({ [field]: e.target.value });
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>
              <div>Item</div>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.props.item.name}
                onChange={this.update("name")}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              <div>Price</div>
              <input
                type="number"
                value={this.props.item.price}
                onChange={this.update("price")}
              />
            </label>
            <div>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Shoule I use store function in redux or is there more easy way?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi tai-fu, welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure I understand your question  It seems like you are having trouble passing the data modified in your `input`s to the server ?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes,I have a trouble passing the data to the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Assumption

I'm assuming that the problem is that the data you can access in your `handleSubmit` function is not being updated, therefore you always receive the values that you initialized the component with.

#### Solution

- Initialize the state based on the `name` and `price` props passed in
- Set the value of your input tags to the state values
- Access the state in your `handleSubmit` function

```js
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class ItemForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.item.name,
      price: this.props.item.price
    }
  }


  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      const ItemData = new FormData();
      ItemData.append("item[name]", this.state.name);
      ItemData.append("item[price]", this.state.price);
    };

  update(field) {
    return (e) => {
      this.setState({ [field]: e.target.value });
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>
              <div>Item</div>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.update("name")}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              <div>Price</div>
              <input
                type="number"
                value={this.state.price}
                onChange={this.update("price")}
              />
            </label>
            <div>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ItemForm);
```

#### Other suggestions

- Your redux wrapper component doesn't have any big effects on this, so you can remove it from this question for clarity

  - This is actually one of the benefits of redux, the connected component (`ItemForm`) is a regular React component and does not have any knowledge that it will be acted on by redux

Hope that helps!

Comment: No problem, hope it helps! If so, please accept this as answer to your question and edit the title and body to better represent the problem as you understand it 